# Read from Chrome storage API on Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I made a Chrome extension which saves and reads data using [`chrome.storage`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage) API.

More specifically, I use [`chrome.storage.sync`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/storage#property-sync). Data is synced using Chrome Sync and works fine on computers.

I would like to access that information on Android devices. Unfortunately, extensions are not supported on Chrome for Android (and they never will, I think).

So, anyone dealt with this scenario before? is it possible to access that information on `chrome.storage` for a Google account somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Cloud Storage JSON API](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/), it stores and retrieves potentially large, immutable data objects.

```
repositories {
mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-storage:v1-rev74-1.22.0'
}
```

The Google Cloud Storage JSON API is intended for software developers. To use it you should be familiar with web programming and be comfortable creating applications that consume web services through HTTP requests

For more information on how to use the google Cloud Storage API, you can use the quick start here: https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstarts

Answer (score -1):

no, its not possible as extensions do not run in mobile chrome and you want to use a chrome extension api.

the Chrome's Sync Filesystem API might help you: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/syncFileSystem

Comment: Do you know if it is possible to use Drive in an extension, like with [Storage API](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_storage) for Chrome apps?

Comment: if you mean "Chrome's Sync Filesystem API" then yes its possible and a good idea so ive added it to the answer.

Comment: I didn't test it yet, but it seems that is only available for apps and not for extensions, am I right?